# mutate a new column to be the row wise maximum

Tags: r

```
 x <- head(iris)
> x
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

If I wanted to mutate a new column onto x called "maximum_num" with values 5.1, 4.9, 4.7 etc how would I do that? (I realize poor example since all would be Sepal.Length here, but if the maximum came from different cols each time)

```
> which.max(x)
Error in which.max(x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I think I can use which.max but not sure how to weave it in.

I also tried

```
x %>% mutate(maxmax = summarise_all(select(., -Species), funs(max)))
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = list(Sepal.Length = 5.4,  : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 6
```

How can I append a new column that contains the maximum row wise values?

is there a dplyr esque way? Also happy with base r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `apply` in the base package:

```
x$maxma=apply(iris[-5],1,max)
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use the vectorized `pmax`

```
x$maxma <- do.call(pmax, iris[-5])
```

Using the `dplyr` chain

```
x %>% 
      mutate(maxma = do.call(pmax, .[-5]))
```

Comment: Something I'm struggling to really get is when to use do.call Vs. looping. If do.call applies a function to a list, when to know to use do.call or e.g. lapply?

Comment: @DougFir   A data.frame is a `list. Only thing is that a `data.frame` is a list with vector of equal length.

Comment: A data.frame is a list. OK. Is it "better" to use do.call to apply a function to a list (a data frame in this case) or lapply? i.e. when to know whether to use do.call or lapply?

Comment: @DougFir  `lapply` is used to loop over the columns and apply a function to that column, but here it is to apply the function over each row.  That is the reason I used `do.call`

Comment: So to solidify my understanding. ```do.call``` would be equivalent to ```apply(df, 1, somfun)```  whereas lapply would be the same but changed to 2 ```apply(df, 2, somfun)```?

Comment: @DougFir Yes, but not all functions work with do.call.  You can do `+`, `paste`, `pmin/pmax` etc